# Should one write Abelian, Noetherian, Artinian by a capital or not?

Tags: mathematics, capitalization

Which one is the correct way to write abstract algebra?

> Let *A* be a **Noetherian** ring.

or

> Let *A* be a **noetherian** ring.

I guess the cases Abelian/abelian, Artinian/artinian behaves similarly.

Comment: [These examples for *Noetherian* are almost exclusively capitalized](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22noetherian%22).  The few that aren't are mostly search engine errors―you'll find that they're capitalized if you look at the actual papers and chapters in question.

Comment: This would probably be a better question for http://math.stackexchange.com since it's specific to mathematical writing.

Answer (score 6):

The word "abelian" is not traditionally capitalized in mathematics, perhaps because it has been generalized to absurdity from where it started. But generally, things named after people in the sciences are capitalized (see J.R.s answer for other exceptions).  Reference:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group#A_note_on_the_typography

Answer (score 5):

Noetherian rings are named after Emmy Noether. I believe that when an adjective is formed from someone's name (or from some other proper noun), that adjective is generally capitalized, particularly in mathematics and science. That's why, in graph theory, *Hamiltonian paths* also use capital H, and why we spell *Newtonian physics* with a capital N.

In contrast, this is not done with the names of elements, even when the names are derived from proper nouns. For example, *californium* and *einsteinium* are spelled with lower-case letters, just like *iron* and *hydrogen*.

Comment: SI units are also officially common nouns and thus not capitalized. So though the SI unit of force is named after Newton and is abbreviated N, they are still officially just *newtons*.

Comment: A notable exception is abelian, which is typically written lower case.

Comment: @anorton - Quite right. It's words like _abelian_ that make English so difficult to master. If only English had rules that were really **rules**! :^)